# Bool in an array selection

Tags: c#

I am need some help on the code that I have. 
I have an array and the boolean selection it give me error. If I erase the boolean line this works fine, but without the selection of gender.

```
private void txt_Name_OnValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listView1.Items.Clear();
    int numberOfRows = 0;
    try
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from workers where name like N'" + txt_Name.Text + "%'", g.con);
        SqlDataAdapter dataapa = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable DT = new DataTable();
        dataapa.Fill(DT);
        for (int i = 0; i < DT.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            string[] arr = new string[6];
            arr[0] = DT.Rows[i]["name"].ToString();
            arr[1] = DT.Rows[i]["num"].ToString();
            arr[3] = DT.Rows[i]["job"].ToString();
            arr[4] = DT.Rows[i]["mail"].ToString();
            arr[5] = DT.Rows[i]["worker_Id"].ToString();
            arr[2] = DT.Rows[i]["gender"].ToString();
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(DT.Rows[i]["gender"]) == true) { arr[2] = "Female"; } else { arr[2] = "Male"; }

            ListViewItem item;
            item = new ListViewItem(arr);
            listView1.Items.Add(item);
            numberOfRows++;
        } lb_num.Text = "number of rows = " + numberOfRows + "";
        lb_num.Visible = true;
    }
    catch { MessageBox.Show("Erro de Servidor"); }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your question to be clearer about what error you're receiving - is this a compilation error? An execution time error? Something else? What exactly is happening? I'd also *very strongly* urge you to use parameterized SQL instead of building your SQL like that.

Comment: A `CREATE TABLE` script so we could see the names and types of the SQL columns would be super helpful.

Comment: in you database select distinct values for gender and see what you have

Comment: Please remove the `catch { MessageBox.Show("Erro de Servidor"); }` - it's a terrible way to deal with errors.

Answer (score 0):

If u are getting "true" or "false" from this piece of code `DT.Rows[i]["gender"].ToString()` then try `bool val = Boolean.Parse(DT.Rows[i]["gender"].ToString())` ,
then try this for conversion

Answer (score 0):

```
            arr[2] = DT.Rows[i]["gender"].ToString();
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(DT.Rows[i]["gender"]) == true) { arr[2] = "Female"; } 
            else { arr[2] = "Male"; }
```

No Logic in here (Convert.ToBoolean(DT.Rows[i]["gender"]) == true): DT.Rows[i]["gender"] if this return "Male" or Female" this will throw a FormatException as Owen answers. In your Db change values to True or false Or To column type  bit type 1 or 0 ,1 for true 0 for false